# How to get the minimum of two metrics in PromQL?

Tags: prometheus, promql

I'm looking for something similar to SQL's LEAST() function.
Since there are binary operators (and a well-defined matching behavior) one would expect there would be min/max as well, but couldn't find such functions.

I'm aware that this is achievable using regex (i.e., `min(__name__=~"a|b")`) but would like to avoid such hacks if possible.

Comment: With [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) this can be done with `min(a, b)`. I'm unsure whether this is possible with PromQL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that's the most efficient way of doing it. If you want to avoid regexes, you could write it instead as:

```
a < b or b
```

But it may be more expensive to compute this way. (Unless, of course, you used recording rules instead of `min(a)` and `min(b)` directly. And maybe even then. You'll just have to benchmark it yourself.)

Comment: I don't understand how this expression would give the least(a, b)

Comment: Sorry, the expression was wrong. Fixed it now. You don't need the `min` operator at all. `min` will produce a single value out of a vector of values, which is likely not what you want here (unless there is only one instance each of your two metrics, in which case it would happen to work).

Comment: The way the expression works is that for every label combination (e.g. `{job="foo",instance="bar"}`, `{job="foo",instance="baz"}` etc.) it will compare the value of `a` and `b`. If `a` is smaller, you get its value. If `b` is smaller, then the expression `a < b` won't return anything for that specific label combination, but the `or b` will return the value of `b`.

Comment: How come `a < b` returns a rather than a boolean?

Comment: RTFM: https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/operators/#arithmetic-binary-operators

Comment: I am guessing that your intention was to state mathematical formula for minimum value of two scalars and the correct representation is this:
syntax 1: min{a,b}={a if a<=b, b if a>b}
syntax 2: if (a<=b) return a else return b
syntax 3: a <= b ? a : b

Answer (score 0):

The question that needs to be asked here is how do you even compare two vectors?

Scalars are comparable - but vectors in general are not.
If you want to compare them you have to define mathematical metrics by which they can be measured.

One needs to have an array of comparable elements in order to determine minimum amongs them.
That is why `min` function in Prometheus has one argument not more. That one argument actually is a list of comparable elements.

For example you can try this:

1. first execute something this:

```
(count(up{squad=~"XYZ"}) by(env))
```

For me the result set looks like this (and more important these are comparable):

```
{env="dev"}         61
{env="preprod"}     39
{env="prod"}        39
```

And then when I execute this:

```
max((count(up{squad=~"XYZ"}) by(env)))
```

I get the result:

```
{}              61
```

Which is expected.

The above will return the environment that has most reachable instances - because before maximum we did agregation (count function) which returned scalar value wich is comparable with other scalar values - which represent number of instances in other environments.